# undefined method `execute_script' for Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation

I'm trying to remove attribute 'readonly' from field. When i tried to do this via **Ruby** i'm getting the following error:

```
element = Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')",date_field)
```

Error:

> undefined method `execute_script' for Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:Class (NoMethodError)

How to resolve this error and remove attribute with ruby selenium?

Comment: `execute_script` method is associated with the `browser`/`driver` instance, but not `WebDriver::Driver`. What's is the browser instance variable in your script? is it `@browser`  or `@driver`?

Comment: its declared globally as $driver and $browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below to check if js is working and then try your js.

```
$browser.execute_script('window.open();')
```